# JIRA Alternative wich allows non users to create issues/tasks

Tags: issue-tracker, task-management, jira

we are currently using JIRA for our software development tasks/issues + general tasks. So basically if someone needs a new feature 1-2 people who have access to jira are creating the new task with the needed information in order to create this request.

Now we want to change this a little bit, so that non-jira users can create their request alone (e.g. a formular to create tasks). In jira there is a thing called "issue collector" which basically does what we need. BUT we have tons of projects (20+) and dont want to create an issue collector for every project - we want the user to select the project on its own.

Since there seems to be no solution with jira, we were wondering if there is anything similar but with the option for non users to create issues/tasks. Since there are also non-software specific projects, we **dont** want to use something like github/gitlab etc.

Does anyone have recommandations? Also should be a web-based solution. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at Trello

Answer (score 2):

Have you already considered using [Jira Service Desk](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/service-desk) instead? It's giving your non-tech users a different view on the issues but your tech users can still work with your issues using the regular view. And you can then link your Jira Service Desk issues with your "internal" Jira issues, so you have a direct connection between them. Since you're already using Jira, I'd definitely recommend it in order to not start with yet another tool by a different software vendor.

Alternatives to Jira for more non-tech users are [Trello](https://trello.com/), [Asana](https://asana.com/), [Basecamp](https://basecamp.com/), [Zenkit](https://zenkit.com/) and many more - just search for "Jira alternatives" and you'll be blown away by all the different products. But as always, it depends on your requirements and what you prefer.